# Magento creating non-ssl links for secure areas

Tags: magento, ssl, nginx, https, fastcgi

my magento store is creating non-ssl / http: links in shopping cart and customer areas. both secure areas are been loaded with https addresses. but, magento keep creating all the links as http instead of https. the cms blocks we create are fine since we use relative links when coding.
how can I fix it? there's something on xml or maybe coding that must be changed?

nginx (ssl settings below) is set to run ssl and it should be fine. but, I'm not sure anymore.

```
server {
  listen       443  default ssl;

  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/mywebsite.com.chained.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/certs/mywebsite.key;

  ssl_session_timeout  5m;

  ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  ....

  location ~* .php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
    expires off;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled HTTPS [via your admin area](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_ssl.htm)?

> System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Secure
>
> - Use Secure URLs in Frontend - yes
> - Use Secure URLs in Admin - yes

Also, do consider updating your SSL settings (ssl_protocols, and ssl_ciphers) to disallow protocols and ciphers with known vulnerabilities and weaknesses. You could probably use [Mozilla's SSL Configuration generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) with appropriate nginx and OpenSSL versions to arrive at a configuration that fits your needs. You can then use a tool like [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) to test your SSL configuration.

A useful guide to configure SSL for Magento:
[How to configure HTTPS (SSL) for Magento](https://blog.amasty.com/how-to-configure-https-ssl-for-magento-bonus/)